# How many simultaneous read instructions per thread on modern GPU?

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

On a modern GPU (let's say, Kepler), if I have 4 independent global memory reads (no dependencies between reads) from a single thread, will all 4 reads be pipelined at once, so that I only pay the latency penalty of a single global memory read? What about from shared memory? How many reads can be in the pipeline at once, is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Probably equal to one of memory controllers of gpu. Such as 64 bit or 2 floats but float2 would be easier for compiler..

Answer (score 2):

The GPU threads do not work in that way. Multiple global memory read from a single thread will never be combined. 
However multiple global memory reads from different threads may be combined if they are launched at the same time, and the locations they are reading are within 128 bytes. This happens in a warp (a group of threads that always execute the same instruction). For example if thread 0~31 in a warp read `input[0~31]` of the type `float`. All these reads will be combine into one memory transaction (assuming the data is properly aligned). But if thread 0~31 in a warp read `input[0,2,4,...,62]`, these read will combine into two memory transactions and half of the data will be read and abandoned.

For shared memory, the latency is ~100x smaller than global memory access. The main concern here is to avoid the bank conflict.

You may want to read the following links for more information.

https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-access-global-memory-efficiently-cuda-c-kernels/

https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc/

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-hierarchy

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#maximize-memory-throughput

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#device-memory-spaces

Comment: I believe your statements are generally correct, but I also suspect the question is asking generally about how many reads can be in flight ("in the pipeline").  AFAIK for global memory this is not documented anywhere and is largely a function of the LD/ST unit and the queues associated with it.  For codes that are well written (i.e. making efficient use of the memory subsystem) it should never be an issue - there is always more capacity in the LD/ST unit to accept transaction requests than those that can be usefully generated from a single thread/warp.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I think he is asking how many reads *in a thread* can be in flight. That has to be 1, right?

Comment: A thread can issue multiple reads (on separate instructions in the instruction stream).  Multiple reads from a single thread can be in flight. A read request *by itself* does not stall the thread. Only when the results of that read are required for a future operation will it stall (if the read data is not available.)  The compiler is aware of this and will attempt to schedule reads before the data are actually required.  In such scenarios, multiple reads (from a single thread or warp) can be in flight.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I see. When he says "pipelined", I thought he means "combined".

Comment: @RobertCrovella - yes, this is what I was asking. If multiple reads are pipelines at once and "in flight", does this mean I pay the latency penalty of only 1 read? You've quite nearly answered the question if you want to answer out of the comments.

Comment: I don't know what "If multiple reads are pipelines at once" means.  GPU programming is largely about *latency hiding*, so for a well written code it may be the case that you never experience the "latency penalty" at all.  Anyway, except in the most general sense, questions asking about when exactly you are going to experience a "latency penalty" in a massively multithreaded architecture are not sensible, to me.